# Linux rename multiple files at once

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I run Ubuntu 20.04.

I have to rename several million files everyday.

Is there a single command or some sort of shell expansion I can use to rename all files at once instead of using a for loop?

**Filenames look like below**

```
1_new.txt, 2_new.txt, 3_new.txt, 4_new.txt
```

**Expected output**

```
1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt
```

Comment: You need to iterate them and rename one by one. Is that a solution for you?

Comment: Pretty sure there's a popular rename command for it.

Comment: you definitely need to iterate through the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me eventually.

```
 rename 's/_new//' *_new.txt
```

I could rename all files through just one command.

Comment: Another convenient tool is the `zmv` command of zsh. Although you are running bash, nothing prevents you to shell out to `zsh` and do a `zsh 'autoload zmv; zmv .....'`. Have a look at `man zshcontrib` and search for _zmv_.  I don't say it's generally better or worse than `rename`, but different enough that you may want to investigate it.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you @user1934428

Answer (score 1):

I also had this challenge to rename my files for a better seo name and found zmv on the oh-my-zsh linux terminal to do it.

For this i published a [live coding video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/JCCcBZVSXYo)

Comment: Thank you Rogoit. Appreciate the kindness to share your solution.